# Error while calling SOAP web-service with Spring

Tags: java, spring, soap

I´m trying to consume a SOAP web-service here, provided by another company.
They sent us the .WSDF file and all .XSD files that are required. So, I generated all Java classes by using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
          <wsdlFile>compass/tran.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <wsdlUrls>
          <wsdlUrl>src/main/resources/compass/tran.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <sourceDestDir>target/generated-sources/compass</sourceDestDir>
        <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
        </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
          </goals>
          <id>generate-reports-ws-code</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My generated class that makes the connection to web-service server has this method:

```
    @WebEndpoint(name = "tran")
public Tran getTran() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran.wsdl", "tran"), Tran.class);
}
```

which returns the interface that has all exposed methods.

Then, I try to make a call to it by doing this, inside my REST service:

```
private Tran compassProxy;
....
compassProxy = new Tran_Service().getTran(); <Here comes the error!!>
invoke = compassProxy.tran(invoke);
```

So, when I run the code, I get an exception from server telling me that occurred an "unexpected end of file after null"
I´m guessing that it´s expecting the request while I´m still connecting to it.

If I make the same call in SoapUI, it works perfectly.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the exception I get from server:

```
Unhandled exception in service "http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran.wsdl" 
request processing:
org.radixware.kernel.server.exceptions.ArteSocketException: Can't receive 
request from /10.45.0.62:50167 : java.io.IOException: Can't parse message: 

Parse exception: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of 
file after null
at org.radixware.kernel.server.instance.arte.ArteProcessor.recvSoapRequest(ArteProcessor.java:777)
at org.radixware.kernel.server.arte.services.Service.process(Service.java:97)
at org.radixware.kernel.server.arte.Arte.processServiceRequest(Arte.java:487)
at org.radixware.kernel.server.instance.arte.ArteProcessor.run(ArteProcessor.java:370)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.radixware.kernel.common.soap.ProcessException: 
java.io.IOException: Can't parse message: 

Parse exception: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
at org.radixware.kernel.common.soap.DefaultServerSoapMessageProcessor.unwrapRequest(DefaultServerSoapMessageProcessor.java:38)
at org.radixware.kernel.server.instance.arte.ArteProcessor.recvSoapRequest(ArteProcessor.java:759)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't parse message: 

Parse exception: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
at org.radixware.kernel.common.utils.SoapFormatter.parseSoapEnvelope(SoapFormatter.java:116)
at org.radixware.kernel.common.utils.SoapFormatter.parseBody(SoapFormatter.java:79)
at org.radixware.kernel.common.utils.SoapFormatter.parseSoapRequest(SoapFormatter.java:127)
at org.radixware.kernel.common.soap.DefaultServerSoapMessageProcessor.unwrapRequest(DefaultServerSoapMessageProcessor.java:36)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3486)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1276)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1250)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.envelope.EnvelopeDocument$Factory.parse(EnvelopeDocument.java:76)
at org.radixware.kernel.common.utils.SoapFormatter.parseSoapEnvelope(SoapFormatter.java:103)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Unexpected end of file after null
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3454)
... 13 more
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I´m using Spring framework here, but it´s not mandatory. I can change it to whatever it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by examining the network traffic with Wireshark to figure out what's different between what you're sending and what SoapUI is sending.

Comment: I´ll take a look at this tool...but is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to tell.  Please read about a [mcve].

Comment: just tell me what else you need and I´ll post here...